# Strange behaviour with e-mails between Django and Google

Tags: django, django-forms, gmail

I have configured my Django settings to send an e-mail using gmail (for password reset)
However, I'm facing a strange behaviour from Google:

- Locally, it works fine, when I use my Django app and I get the report that an email has been sent;
- Deployed on DigitalOcean, using the shell, it works fine:

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail("Objet3", "Message body", "from.eg@gmail.com",['to.eg@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
1
```

However, when using the deployed app, I always get a Server Error 500, which is reported as such by Sentry:

```
SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError f6sm10267338edk.13 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

It's really puzzling, as at Gmail:

- I have decreased the level of security,
- I have created an App pass and implemented it...
  Does anyone have an idea, where it may come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does not want to be an email provider like this so they've made it increasingly difficult. Look into a provider such as sendgrid, mailgun, or [others](https://www.g2.com/products/mailgun/competitors/alternatives).

Comment: This what I guessed, and thank you for your reply. 
However, I remain puzzled by this behaviour: solely when I use my App + deployed, it blocks. :-/

Comment: Check out the link https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError in the error. It could be because you're accessing the account too often.

Comment: I would like to, but no: I can send several e-mails in a row, without any problem.
Changing the provider as proposed by schillingt would be an option, but I would largely prefer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Finally SendGrid was a reasonable and practical solution, as I could configure it to :

- send e-mails with my own domain name,
- certify the e-mail so it doesn't fall into the spams
  and they have a plan for free, absolutely useful in development phase.

Thank you Schillingt for your piece of advice.